# HTML dropdown menu not functioning

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner at html and I am trying to begin working on my online portfolio, I have gotten the nav bar set up and now I am trying to make a drop down menu from the nav bar. So far I have not been able to get the items to even go into the drop down menu, so I am thinking I do not have the container set up correctly. Thank you ahead of time!

```css
/* nav bar */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
 
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;  
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
 
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 150px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
 
  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  */
  
  /*****************************************************************/
  /*Dropdown for portfolio tab */
  /*****************************************************************/
  /* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title> Will's Portfolio </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css">
<link href='http://fonts.gooleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>
<body background = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Xmo26BMqg5Q/UihlqVwTwgI/AAAAAAAAAv0/V-Rrgm0V6oo/s1600/Top+10+best+Simple+Awesome+Background+Images+for+Your+Website+or+Blog3.jpg">
<body  class="About Me">
 <header>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
   
   
   
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>    
      
    <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Portfolio</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Graphics</a>
     <a href="#">Other</a>
     
      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><nobr>Future Work</nobr></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div> 
  

 </header>
</div>
  
  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The element with the `dropdown-content` class is inside the element with the `dropdown` class, so what you are looking for is actually `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`

You current code (the `+` char) tells your browser to check for an adjacent sibling (and not a child element), which is not your case.

This is the update for your code:

```css
/* nav bar */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
 
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;  
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
 
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 150px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
 
  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  */
  
  /*****************************************************************/
  /*Dropdown for portfolio tab */
  /*****************************************************************/
  /* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title> Will's Portfolio </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css">
<link href='http://fonts.gooleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>
<body background = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Xmo26BMqg5Q/UihlqVwTwgI/AAAAAAAAAv0/V-Rrgm0V6oo/s1600/Top+10+best+Simple+Awesome+Background+Images+for+Your+Website+or+Blog3.jpg">
<body  class="About Me">
 <header>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
   
   
   
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>    
      
    <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Portfolio</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Graphics</a>
     <a href="#">Other</a>
     
      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><nobr>Future Work</nobr></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div> 
  

 </header>
</div>
  
  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is with this CSS selector:

```
.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

It should be:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
/* nav bar */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
 
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;  
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
 
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 150px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
 
  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  */
  
  /*****************************************************************/
  /*Dropdown for portfolio tab */
  /*****************************************************************/
  /* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title> Will's Portfolio </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css">
<link href='http://fonts.gooleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>
<body background = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Xmo26BMqg5Q/UihlqVwTwgI/AAAAAAAAAv0/V-Rrgm0V6oo/s1600/Top+10+best+Simple+Awesome+Background+Images+for+Your+Website+or+Blog3.jpg">
<body  class="About Me">
 <header>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
   
   
   
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>    
      
    <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Portfolio</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">Graphics</a>
     <a href="#">Other</a>
     
      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><nobr>Future Work</nobr></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div> 
  

 </header>
</div>
  
  


</body>
</html>
```